# How to put Python threads in multiple queues and run it in the order it was added?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

I've got a WebSocket client and I want to process messages in threads that are split to multiple queues based on the content of the data.

I receive messages in specific order, I want to run functions that are processing messages in this order, but only within categories.

[image: graph]

What I managed to do is to create a solution that does not respect the messages order:

```
def start():
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
        "ws://127.0.0.1:8080/",
        on_message=on_message,
    )
    Thread(target=ws.run_forever).start()

def on_message(ws, data):
    Thread(target=process_data, args=(data,).start() # here I want to preserve order
    # here should be categorizing and queuing threads

def process_data(data):
    # here should wait for running thread in its category to end, 
    # and then become a running thread and process data
```

I can't use thread.join() in the on_message because it will block the main thread, I want to preserve messages order in this method. It need to be blocking after categorizing, each category in its own threads queue.

Maybe i should queue messages instead of threads?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simple approach:

```
q = Queue()
def worker_thread():
    while True:
         msg = q.get()
         if msg.cat == A:
             process A
         if msg.cat == B:
             process B

Thread(target=worker_thread).start()

while True:
      # receive message
      if A:
          q.put((A, message))
      if B:
          q.put((B, message))
```